# Access internet via Apache2 ProxyPass

Tags: security, ssl, proxy, dns, vpn

Recently, I made a setup where I pointed some websites to a redirect server. The redirect server in return served the website requests using ProxyPass directive of Apache2. It worked like a charm without even a single problem for my websites.

So, based on that I have got an idea to access internet via Apache2. Please note that this is because I do not have access to fast internet and every internet provider is so lousy and lame here to provide better connection speeds even for the lot of money I pay to them.

Now, https as better speends than VPN.
So, the idea is to get rid of VPN and SSH tunnel redirects and instead, resolve every domain on my Mac to a single server IP address which should be a redirect server and which can in turn bring me back every web request made from my Mac. Possible? This will make me to always use https to my own redirect server. https has better speed than VPN for me whenever I try and when I am on VPN things are too slow for me, may be because of level of encryption. Please note that I do not want solution using PPTP, L2TP and anything else which are lighter than OpenVPN (using Pritunl).

Please let me know if anything like that is possible and if yes then how.

Even though if it does not work, my mind always gets this idea every time. I just want someone to shed light on this and shut down my idea if its the worst by far. Thanks in advance.

Also, I have also seen some proxy sites where I put any website link on their website and their website works like a browser as if I am surfing on their remote server itself. May be something like that can be useful and speedy for me. But, I do not want to use them because I do not trust those sites for security. No way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution myself without any kind of VPN.
Actually I needed to make my DNS secure and connections to my server Apps secure. So, for that I tried DNSCrypt-Proxy and its working great and resolving my DNS queries on HTTPS (443).

And, I am using an Addon on Chrome for "Always https" connections. I am blocking every request on http for Chrome using that Addon. Perfect!!!

So, now all surfing traffic on my Mac is going on HTTPS and is perfectly safe from hackers. I do not care for any other connections made by my other Mac Apps. I just care for security of my Apps while I am surfing them OR any payments I am making for shopping.

1. DNSCrypt-Proxy:
   Please go to https://dnscrypt.org/#dnscrypt-osx and you will find all help there to how to install and run it on your Mac.

brew install dnscrypt-proxy --with-plugins

sudo dnscrypt-proxy --ephemeral-keys --resolver-name=cisco

^ You can find the resolver name in excel sheet that comes with this package.

And, just add an entry in your Network interfaces for DNS to point to 127.0.0.1, Please note that remove all other entries.

2. "Always HTTPS for Chrome": 
   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/https-everywhere/gcbommkclmclpchllfjekcdonpmejbdp?hl=en

Enjoy perfect security on your Mac, if you do not care about IP address anonymity. Always use legal stuff!!!